# Generating an RSA Key Pair with Erlang?

Tags: erlang, cryptography, rsa, public-key, private-key

Erlang has a crypto function which generates public private keys (documentation copied below).  However the documentation seems vague and I can't find any example code that describes how to generate the shared prime number or the generator.  Can someone post an example that generates a public/private key pair?  Thanks in advance for any help!

```
dh_generate_key(DHParams) -> {PublicKey,PrivateKey} 
dh_generate_key(PrivateKey, DHParams) -> {PublicKey,PrivateKey}
```

Types:
DHParameters = [P, G]
P, G = Mpint
Where P is the shared prime number and G is the shared generator.
PublicKey, PrivateKey = Mpint()
Generates a Diffie-Hellman PublicKey and PrivateKey (if not given).

Comment: Do you know the difference between RSA and Diffie-Hellman?

Comment: It might help if you explained why you needed an RSA key pair.  No offense, but if you're confusing RSA and DH, you might be unknowingly trying to use an encryption algorithm that's inappropriate for your application.  Maybe we can suggest one that fits better.

Comment: If you just want to get a pair of public key and private key for RSA, try this: `crypto:generate_key(rsa, {1024, 3})`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't generate the shared prime number or the generator for Diffie-Hellman.  See:

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie-Hellman_key_exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange)

The parameters P and G are agreed to ahead of time by both sides.  Using the notation of the Wikipedia article, `crypto:dh_generate_key` is used for steps 2 & 3 to generate `a`/`A` & `b`/`B`, and then `crypto:dh_compute_key` is used for steps 4 & 5 to compute the shared secret `s`.

For [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA), I don't know of a standard library function that generates a public/private key pair.  Generating primes is a fairly involved algorithm from what I remember; I would strongly recommend you not try to code it yourself.  Diffie-Hellman key pairs *are not suitable* for use with RSA; they are different algorithms intended for different purposes.

Generally you don't need to generate these at runtime since you can reuse the key pair.  You can use any number of other sources to actually generate it.  (Maybe ssh-keygen would work?  And there's always [OpenSSL](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Transwiki:Generate_a_keypair_using_OpenSSL).)  To use the key pair you've created, you'd use the `crypto:rsa_ public/private _ encrypt/decrypt` functions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the crypto:generate_key/2 function to create RSA public and private keys:

For a 2048 length

```
{Pub, Priv} = crypto:generate_key(rsa, {2048,65537}).
```

Or for a 1024 length

```
{Pub, Priv} = crypto:generate_key(rsa, {1024,65537}).
```

See: https://erlang.org/doc/apps/crypto/crypto.pdf (page 37)

```
generate_key(Type, Params) -> {PublicKey, PrivKeyOut}
```

Where

```
Type = rsa


Params = rsa_params() =
    {ModulusSizeInBits :: integer(),
     PublicExponent :: key_integer()}
```

Answer (score 2):

See cutkey (https://github.com/yrashk/cutkey)

> "cutkey is an Erlang app for generating RSA keys. It is implemented as
>   a port driver that calls OpenSSL's RSA_generate_key on a thread from
>   the async pool."

Answer (score 2):

os:command("openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out private_key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048").